# How to Loop the data which is in sheet1 based on sheet2 reference and print in notepad

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets. sheet1 has the data and sheet2 has the maximum length 
of each cell which refers the data in sheet1.

I can loop one time but not able to loop second set of messages in loop

Sheet1 has 2 set of data from row 1 to 6 and 7 to 12
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyids.jpg

Sheet2 has max character length and it has to use for row 7 to 12
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JbBC.jpg

Output should be like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9dQ5.jpg

Sheet1 row 1 to 6 refers the sheet2 but I am not able to loop the same 
reference for 7 to 12.

Please note
In notepad, after EODR second message should print.

And my code is,
Sub myself()

```
Dim str As String
Dim MaxStrLen As String
Dim rest As Integer
Dim Lstr As Integer
Dim LMstr As Integer
Dim MStr As Integer
Dim LR As Range
Dim CNT As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim h As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim FilePath As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

Open "C:\Users\Antony\Music\Excel Macros\Test.txt" For Output As #2
```

'''''FIRST FIVE LINES WILL PRINT IN THE NOTEPAD

```
With ws1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LastRow
    sOut = vbNullString
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        str = .Cells(i, j).Value
        MStr = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
        Lstr = Len(str)
        rest = MStr - Lstr
        sOut = sOut & str & Space(rest)
    Next
    Print #2, sOut
Next
End With
```

'''''LAST LINE WILL PRINT IN THE SAME NOTEPAD

```
With ws3
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

slast = vbNullString

For k = 2 To LRow
  str = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(k, 
       "A").Resize(1, LastCol).Value)), "@#")
  str = Replace(str, "=", vbNullString)

    Print #2, str
Next

Endtext = "EODR"

Print #2, slast & Endtext

End With


Close #2

End Sub
```

If there is more messages, I need to loop, Kindly help me to solve

Comment: Can anyone help me on this pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this issue

> Sheet1 row 1 to 6 refers the sheet2 but I am not able to loop the same reference for 7 to 12.

modify the middle block this way:

```
BlkSize=6              ' your data consists of blocks of 6 rows
For i = 1 To LastRow
    sOut = vbNullString
    LengthRow = i
    Do While LengthRow > BlkSize
        LengthRow = LengthRow - BlkSize
    Loop
' now LengthRow points to row where char length is to be taken from
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        str = .Cells(i, j).Value
        MStr = ws2.Cells(LengthRow, j).Value
        Lstr = Len(str)
        rest = MStr - Lstr
        sOut = sOut & str & Space(rest)
   Next
   Print #2, sOut
Next
```

Comment: @AcsEmo this is what I want and exactly it is working fine. Thank you